# Возможна ли локализация UI элементов в Xcode iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Возможно ли наитивным образом поставить, чтобы надпись в searcBar для отмены была не "cancel", а "отмена", в TableView при commitEditingStyle были надписи в строках не "Delete", а "Удалить". Это вообще возможно как то прописать в настройках среды, или где еще, или только самому прописывать можно? В симуляторе стоит в настройках русский язык. Искал в сети на обоих языках - нашел информацию только что для подобных элементов язык сам должен правильный выставляться, но в моем случае этого не происходит. Работаю в Xcode 5, iOS 7 SDK. 
Для SearchBar пробовал этот способ:

```
 [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] 
                                         setTitle:@"Отмена" 
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Не помогло.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно возможно, все базовые вещи переводятся автоматом, если вы включаете поддержку других языков в своем проекте. Все остальные строки локализуются либо через **NSLocalizedString** либо через **Base Internationalization** в **Storyboard**. Все строки в сториборде могут быть локализованы, делается это также при добавлении Base в список Languages (у вашей сториборды появляются локализованные варианты). В UISearchBar кнопка будет локализована автоматическии, если вы добавите язык в **Проект** (вверху слева в дереве навигации по проекту) -> далее следует выбрать проект (не target) -> вкладка **Info** -> раздел **Localizations** - **список языков**.

[image]

Чтобы локализовывать свои UI элементы - `self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Sting to be localized", @"comment for translator");`

вот хороший  туториал по локализации (теперь на русском): [http://www.raywenderlich.com/ru/36227/Локализация-приложений-в-ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/ru/36227/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-ios)

а по сторибордам там вроде и так все предельно ясно будет, единственное, autolayout должен быть включен